# Android NDK in Eclipse Type size_t could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, android-ndk

I'm getting the follow error: "Type 'size_t' could not be resolved" on android ndk project, but I already added the library paths:

```
/Users/ademar/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include
/Users/ademar/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport
/Users/ademar/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/include
```

so i not understand why this error.

---

code where I get the error:

```
static inline bool simplejson_wcsnlen(const wchar_t *s, size_t n)
```

---

I added each one of headers described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) but still not working.

---

I Tried the follow:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" {
    JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_xxx_getStringFromJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jstring param) {
        size_t x;
        return env->NewStringUTF("test");
    }
}
```

and it also not work...

Comment: please, post the offending code.

Comment: I think you need to include the header that defines size_t.  and you probably have to use std::size_t.

Comment: @AnonMail I'm added the '<stdio.h>' its correct to use std::? so with it dont works :/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

size_t is defined in stddef.h which is compiler specific. In order to add it to the include path you have to add the /toolchain//prebuilt//lib/**gcc**///include to your path.

For example for building an android app on 64bit windows machine using ndk, you have to add `<NDK-PATH>\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.8\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib\gcc\arm-linux-androideabi\4.8\include` to your path.

Comment: Preprocessor Include, Macros etc -> Entries (CDT User Entries) -> Add
And check -> Contains system headers